# How to detect whether the object has triangular shape?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

The task is to detect arrow from medical images. After segmenting, arrow-like objects can be connected with other connected components (noise). In this context, detecting a part of the object that characterizes an arrowhead would be a solution since template based shape descriptor does not perform well.
Please help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you can find the orientation of the arrow using principal component analysis (or fitting an ellipse and taking major/minor axis directions).

To locate the arrow head, use distance transform. You'll have to preprocess the image, like flood-filling the region. Because the arrow head base is usually the widest part of the image, you should get a peak there.

Now you can use this point along with the two orthogonal vectors calculated earlier. In the image below I've translated those vectors to go through the distance-transform peak(I didn't do any calculations, the image is just for illustration).

[image]

The blue axis (second component in PCA or the minor axis of ellipse) now divides the image into two halves, and if you take projection of each half on to the blue axis, the half that contains the arrow head should give you a triangular profile (blue and orange profiles in the image below).

[image]

**EDIT**

Another approach would be to use the distance transform peak to isolate the neighborhood of the arrow head. If we threshold the distance transformed image by some fraction of the peak value, for the arrow head we should still get a triangular shape. Now we can prepare a mask centered on the peak to extract this region. Below is a simple Matlab code that does this for a specific image:

```
im = imread('arrow.jpg');
gray = rgb2gray(im);
bw = im2bw(gray, graythresh(gray));
di = bwdist(bw);
[mx, mxidx] = max(di(:));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(di), mxidx);
bw2 = di > mx*.5;
se = strel('disk', double(ceil(mx*1.5)), 0);
mask = zeros(size(bw2));
mask(ypeak, xpeak) = 1;
mask = imdilate(mask, se);
figure,
subplot(1, 3, 1), imshow(bw), title('binary')
subplot(1, 3, 2), imshow(bw2.*di, []), title('thresholded dist')
subplot(1, 3, 3), imshow(mask.*di.*bw2, []), title('masked')
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a nice suggestion. We are still having problem with the following arrow variants: a) curved arrows, arrow (just a triangle). In this context, detection triplet (from arrow head would be a possible solution). Thanks!

Comment: Anybody body has any idea of detecting arrowhead from an object?

Comment: Idea related to projection profiles: You can find the peak and area of the profile, then derive isosceles triangle having the same area and height. Now if you do a cross-correlation between the profile and the triangle, I think you should get a high similarity for triangular profile.

Comment: @ Dhanushka, Do you think you get the peak from the curved arrows? or when other objects are connected at the tail?

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. Isn't it possible to remove other connected objects, for example, using some morphological filtering? It'll be helpful if you can post some more images covering these cases so people can get a better idea.

Comment: @ Dhanushka, Projection profile technique may not work on the arrow shown below (thats an example) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YM8fp.png) Therefore, whatever the shape of the arrow, there exists triplet points (arrowhead points in a triangular format). If we can detect those three points, we can win! Any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the very nice reply (using dist, and peak criterion). How about separating arrow-like objects from others? Is that possible too?
The following are the examples ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEmNg.jpg)
![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8aRt6.jpg)
![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hptMD.jpg)
![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NXDva.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and add a comment to the answer if you want to draw the attention. Do not edit an answer to ask another question.

Comment: When you use distance-transform approach, how does it work for non-arrow like objects? Did you try using this difference(if there is any) to differentiate?